# Shell script - Read content on Server#1, process on Server#2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to work on a current logfile, hosted on Server#1, without being ON Server#1.
How can I read the content, to get scripts process on an other machine (Server#2)

I don't want Server#1 to be impacted by my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh` to get the log file contents, and pipe it to the script running locally:

```
ssh Server1 cat logfile | path/to/script
```

Comment: Is copying a file (possibly large logfile) not impacting the server it is being copied from? The question contains "I don't want Server#1 to be impacted by my scripts."

Comment: There's no way to get the data from server1 without impacting it somehow. All you can do is minimize the impact.

Comment: What you might consider is to use forwarding of syslog messages to Server#2. That way it would not impact its normal operation as much as cat'ing a whole logfile.

Comment: additionally, you can do `MY_VARIABLE="$(ssh Server1 cat logfile)"` inside your script, and analyse/process the resulting variable

Comment: Yes, there are numerous variations on this basic theme.

Answer (score -1):

`scp`, netcat, FTP, `rsync`... you have so many options.